# Pulling Data off PNG map scan using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, png, vectorization

I have scanned a map with several trade routes on it and georeferenced it on top of a hydrology (river system) map of the U.S. The scanned map is a PNG file.

How can I pull off the trade routes?

End Goal: story map showing the evolution of the Rocky Mountain Fur Companys trade network.

Comment: raster to vector (arcscan is required) http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/what-is-arcscan-.htm

Comment: Or just manually digitize them.

Comment: It depends on how many and how complex (background 'noise' you're not interested in), it might be quicker and simpler to heads-up digitize as @GBG indicates if there's only a few *but* if your trade routes are like contours over the Rocky Mountains or if the trade routes are the only thing on your scan it might be quicker to use some sort of supervised classification and clean up the vectors produced.. how bad *is* your data?

Comment: or use an online service like https://vectormagic.com/ pdf can easily be converted to dxf for arcgis.